# Can a subring contain idempotent element the bigger ring does not

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring and $D\subseteq R$ a subring.
Can $D$ contain idempotent elements, i.e. elements $e\in D:e^2=e$, that are not idempotent in $R$.

I'm fairly sure this is true, and I believe the proof should be almost trivial, but I don't see it.
Since taking a quotient ring as the subring, it might create more idempotents, although I don't have an example thus don't know if this can happen.

Comment: If $e\in D\subseteq R$ is an idempotent of $D$ then it is also an idempotent of $R$ since $e\in R$.

Comment: @Deif well I can see that $e/in R$ when $e\in D$, but does $e^2=e$ also hold in $R$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it cannot. This follows from what it means to be a "subring": multiplication of $e*e$ "in $D$" is the same as their multiplication "in $E$". And if you feel the need to get super-basic, we can also note that equality of elements is not affected by what set/sets they are in.

If you want to consider a more general situation than being a subring, like image under a ring homomorphism, we can note that being an idempotent is conserved: $\phi(e)*\phi(e) =\phi(e*e)=\phi(e)$.

Two other things to note: 1 - To create a quotient ring you need an ideal, not just a subring, and 2 - The idea of "introduce new idempotents" could use a bit more precision. I'll take it to mean "there are idempotents in the range that aren't the image of of an idempotent in the domain". For a non-surjective homomorphism, it's an easy yes: $a \mapsto (a,0)$, where the idempotent $(0,1)$ pops up.

But if you restrict yourself to surjective homomorphisms (which, as the first homomorphism theorem tells us, is the same thing as any quotient map), .... I'm not sure. I'd make a bet that you can introduce new idempotents, but my brain isn't giving me an example just now. Maybe you could try to come up with one?

Comment: Ah yes, I did see that $e\in R$ for $e \in D$, but I didn't realise the multiplication would also be the same, thank you!

Comment: I mean, you could have a different multiplication inside D, but then you don't get to use the term "subring".

Comment: Precisely, the multiplication must be the same, hence the resulting element after multiplication must be the same in a subring.